# While Serializing a java object to a file is it possible to insert an object at the beginning of the serialized file

Tags: java, serialization

I am trying to serialize N number of objects to a file. whenever I serialize a list of objects I write the number on objects I am about to serialize as an int before the objects are serialized. While de-serializing i read the int value first and i will get the number of times I have to call the ObjectInputStream.readObject().

But in this case value of N is known only at runtime.

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("c:\\testfile");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);

oos.writeInt(/* number of objects here */); <- Can't do as the total is unknown till 
                                               last object is encountered

/* done N-times
 oos.writeObject(eachString);
*/

oos.close();
fout.close();
```

I tried this and it doesn't work

```
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("c:\\testfile", "rw");
f.seek(0); // to the beginning
f.writeInt(s.size());
f.close();

Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000003
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:298)
at testPack.testSerialization.main(testSerialization.java:44)
```

I have already gone through this question

[Java Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788182/java-serialization)

I don't want to write the N-Objects as a list, as that would require me to keep the complete list into memory.

So, I was wondering if there is another way of doing it that would involve changing the contents of the serialized file (inserting the int value somewhere at the top).

Comment: readObject will throw an exception when there's no object to be read... Why not just read untill exception is thrown and catch it

Comment: I agree, we can catch the EOFException. This is the method I am gonna go with for the time being. But, I am still curious if it can be done the other way as well.

Comment: Klas's method shows some promise... Are you certain it won't work?

Comment: @Thihara It doesn't even compile.

Comment: @EJP His general idea I mean, I didn't try the code...

Comment: Well that answer's gone :D

Answer (score 0):

Have your thought of placing the objects inside an ArrayList and serialize/deserialise the ArrayList itself?

[ArrayList implements Serialisable...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Yes, but doing so would require me to hold the whole ArrayList in memory which I don't want to do at all. The number of objects that i am going to write could be a lot.

Comment: You can create the array only for the serializetion. If they are already in memory, then placing them in an ArrayList won't change a lot (it holds only the pointers). Another option would be to save them separately in different files. I wouldn't recommend trying to save one container and pull out only one object directly from the file

Comment: The objects arrive from a file and are written after some processing. I hold only 1 or 2 objects in memory at any given time.